# Show Sidebar And Dashboard Component after user gets logged In in angular

Tags: angular

I want to show Dashboard and Sidebar Component while user successfully logs in. Currently my sidebar component and dashboard component loads only after I refresh my page.

I tried navigating this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard'); after user successfully login in onClickSubmit function

```
onClickSubmit() {
    this.isValidFormSubmitted = false;
     if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        this.formErrorSubmit = true; 
        return;
     }
     this.isValidFormSubmitted = true;
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
    //  this.loginForm.reset();
  }
```

Html file

```
<div id="main" class="page-wrapper" [ngClass]="{'toggled' : getSideBarState()}">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    <main class="page-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- <div class="overlay" (click)="toggleSidebar()" [ngClass]="{'show' : !getSideBarState()}"></div> -->
    </main>
</div>
```

Routing file

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component:LoginComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent},
  {path: 'calendar', component:CalendarComponent},
];
```

sidebar service

```
toggled = false;
 toggle() {
    this.toggled = ! this.toggled;
  }

  getSidebarState() {
    return this.toggled;
  }
```

Dashboard and Sidebar component should be shown after successful log in.

Comment: There must be parent child relation in these (Dashboard and SideBar) both compoents!

Comment: Show how the app.module looks like

Comment: See I have added in question

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: My sidebar component is only gets shown after I refresh after successful login I want to display both sidebar component and dashboard component both after successful login.

Comment: Are you showing Component based on this function? -- `getSideBarState()`?

Comment: Yes I am. I guess there is not an issue because of this getSideBarState() because sidebar component get shown after I refresh the page.

Comment: Can you show the code of that method?

Comment: I have added in question now.

Comment: Can you try to that variable in localStorage and then access from there

Comment: Not working in localStorage

Comment: Have implemented simple demo with shared service: https://stackblitz.com/edit/shared-service-4kevkb

Answer (score 0):

use this one works

```
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
```

Comment: Not working. I want to show sidebar and dashboard component after successful login

Comment: can you please share your route.module.ts

Comment: i am asking where you mapped your component and route that file

Comment: go through this example it will help
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-registration-login-example?file=app%2Fapp.routing.ts

Answer (score 0):

Use angular routing as the following example. For that, you have to create a routing function.

```
  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService, private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    const redirectUrl = route['_routerState']['url'];

    if (this.customerService.isLogged()) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigateByUrl(
      this.router.createUrlTree(
        ['/login'], {
          queryParams: {
            redirectUrl
          }
        }
      )
    );

    return false;
  }
```

Then in your component.ts file give the routing path as follows,

```
this.isValidFormSubmitted = true;
 this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
```

Furthermore follow [this example](https://medium.com/@ozgurgul/angular-6-login-and-router-tutorial-ac5fc5d3027f) . If you have any questions feel free to comment below. Thank you!